# Image Array: Out of range exception

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, image, exception

I am making a small game in `C#` and I am trying to load images into an `array`, but it keeps saying the **index is out of range**.

Here's the part that is giving me an error:

```
Image[] Map = new Image[10];
Image map1 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map1.png");
Map[1] = map1;
Image map2 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map2.png");
Map[1] = map2;
Image map3 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map3.png");
Map[1] = map3;
Image map4 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map4.png");
Map[1] = map4;
Image map5 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map5.png");
Map[1] = map5;
Image map6 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map6.png");
Map[1] = map6;
Image map7 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map7.png");
Map[1] = map7;
Image map8 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map8.png");
Map[1] = map8;
Image map9 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map9.png");
Map[1] = map9;
Image map10 = Image.FromFile("_Maps_\\map10.png");
Map[1] = map10;
```

I am a bit new to arrays in `C#`

If you need more code just ask

Comment: That can't be the actual code that gives the error. You are putting all the images in the same item in the array, so you end up with an array containing the last image and 9 null references, but no error.

Comment: Oh oops, sorry for waisting your time. I didn't notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a easy way to load this images using LINQ, see below:

```
Image[] Map = Directory.GetFiles("_Maps_", "*.png")
                       .Select(file => Image.FromFile(file))
                       .ToArray();
```

Using this way you wont care about name of maps, and if you add a new map, it will be taken from this code.

You can simplify this code a little bit

```
Image[] Map = Directory.GetFiles("_Maps_", "*.png")
                       .Select(Image.FromFile)
                       .ToArray();
```